# User draw shapes on top of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I would want to allow user to draw semi-transparent basic shapes (rectangle, circle) with user defined text over an image. The basic idea is to have a map underneath and users could mark certain areas of from it. It has been a while since doing web development and I'm quite uncertain which approach would be the best. It should work even on older browsers.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To have it work with non-html5-browsers you'll certainly need some script language (javascript, flash, ...).

Comment: Flash is also something I would like to stay away from. Is there any good javascript libraries to use? I tried searching something for jquery, but didnt really find anything useful.

Comment: It would be great if you could describe what you have, what you need and what you tried so far (chance to make a picture of your idea?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, forget about old browsers, it's 2012 after all. You won't be able to draw circle without having such css properties as "border-radius".

Second, no matter what, you'll have to use javascript in order to do the "drawing". jQuery + jQuery UI would be great for that. It appears like you'd need at least following plugins:

- [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) - to drag your shapes around
- [Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) - to resize shapes
- [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) - to put text into the shape (there must be a textarea within the dialog. After you fill textarea and click Ok text will be put into the shape).

There's another way to put text into shapes, but that'll require some serious development efforts.

Now, how to create shapes. There are couple of ways:

1. Button which you'll have to click and which will create a box with set parameters
2. Use [boxer](http://jsbin.com/azare) plugin

That's the gist of it.

Rendering of the saved shapes is quite a different thing and i believe it shouldn't be problematic. Just fetch data from DB and based on it's properties render shapes.

Comment: "Forget about old browsers" may be nice if you're coding a personal project in your home office, but often isn't acceptable to a client who is paying you.

Comment: Using javascript is quite fine, I just wasnt sure if there would other options aswell. Added tags to javascript and jquery now. Drawing circles is a bit optional, but I see your point about the old browsers. It would be quite important to at least display them even on older browsers, even if the actual drawing would not work. Thank you for all the info!

Comment: @Grim..., in that case you have to explain to the customer what is possible and what is impossible on old browsers.
-----
Kemu79, displaying shouldn't be an issue. After you done with the shape it's properties must be saved in DB and then you'll draw nice shape with PHP or any other language. It's the drawing process in itself which is dependent on new browsers.